# Disable DataGridView except the scroll

Tags: c#, datagridview, disabled-control

How I can configure a datagridview so that the user can only move through the rows and use the scroll, and nothing else...
If I disable the grid not allow me to use the scroll

Comment: What do you mean by nothing else ? Can't the user even click it ;)

Comment: I do not care that it can not select rows but if I want to Scroll

Comment: Do you mean 'how can make the datagrid read only ?'

Comment: If i make the datagrid read only then user could do doble-click in a row for example.

Comment: Yes, only if you have handlers attached to the click events of the grid. If you don't, it shouldn't be an issue. If you do, you could check in your handlers if your grid is read-only and do nothing.

Comment: I tried it and it's very successful. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your datagridview to read-only, this will disable any edits.

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
```

And inside your handlers, do :

```
void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (dataGridView1.ReadOnly == true)
          return;

     // .. whatever code you have in your handler...
}
```

Even if the user double-clicks on the grid, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in OP comments:

```
dataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
```

Inside any DataGridView events you are handling, check the ReadOnly property and do not do anything inside the event if true.

I looked at another option of iterating through rows and columns and disabling each of them, but Enabled is not a property of the row or column object. Iterating through a large number of items would be slow, anyway.

Comment: If i make the datagrid read only then user could do doble-click in a row for example. I´ve tried remove doble-click event handler from the grid but it doesn´t works.

Comment: How is that a problem if nothing happens when the user double-clicks ?

Comment: T. Fabre has the solution: evaluate ReadOnly datagridview property on the double-click event.

Answer (score 1):

T. Fabre answer didn't work for me. In my case, I have buttons and editable checkboxes for each row of my datagrid, so they won't be deactivated even if the DataGrid is in ReadOnly. However, what did work for me (without disabling the scroll) is disabling each row like in this example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="MyDataGridRowStyle">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

And then in the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ... RowStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridRowStyle}">
```

Hope that helps (sorry if only posted the XAML solution)!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for me that disables everything except scrolling and resizing cells (which imho is best for "read only tables"):

```
// disable editing
this.dgTabOptions.ReadOnly = true;

// disable selection        
private void myGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgTabOptions.ClearSelection();
}

//disable sorting
private void dgTabOptions_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```