# DataGrid Set ReadOnly and allow scrolling?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scroll, readonly

I have a `DataGrid`, where I currently set to `ReadOnly` when I don't want the user to change anything, then I have a button for the user to click to allow Modify, which then changes `IsReadOnly` to false

but the problem now is that when the `DataGrid.IsReadOnly = true`, the scrolling is disabled. How do I make it so that the DataGrid `IsReadOnly=true` or similar and still be able to scroll the `DataGrid`?

DataGrid Style:

```xml
<DataGrid.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding ReadOnly}" Value="True"/>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding Reordering}" Value="False"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
          <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
          <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
      </MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding ReadOnly}" Value="True"/>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding Reordering}" Value="True"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
          <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
          <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
      </MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding ReadOnly}" Value="False"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
          <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True" />
          <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
      </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (dataGridView1.ReadOnly == true)
          return;

     // .. whatever code you have in your handler...
}
```

[Disable DataGridView except the scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750518/disable-datagridview-except-the-scroll)

Comment: I'm accepting this because its a good way for people to handle ReadOnly, but I couldn't use this because of the events and triggers that it would prevent me from using.